# what's the relationship between memory bus width and cpu cache performance?

Tags: cpu, cpu-cache

I have develop c++ for a while, and I studied cache line performance. And now I am wondering how the memory bus related with cpu cache performance as well. if the cache line is 64 byte (typically), and memory width is 192 bits on a i7 cpu. does that mean to read a cache line of data from heap, it take multiple cpu cycle (64 byte / 24 byte)?

Comment: The three memory channels are independent (i.e., interleaved at a coarser granularity than cache line), so a single cache line is filled from only one 64-bit channel. The speed of the memory interface depends on the memory itself not the processor speed; DDRx memory transfers 2 per *memory cycle*  per lane (e.g., 1 GHz DDR3 [advertised as 2 GHz, PC3 16000 DIMM]: 16 GB/s per 64-bit channel). Achieved bandwidth is more complex, depending on access pattern, and latency of the total access (and not just transfer latency) is another factor (which also depends of access pattern).

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton So to improve the cache reading performance, faster RAM make the most impact (ignoring the program itself)? Could you give other possible bottleneck as well?

Comment: The latency of a DRAM access depends on bank and channel conflicts. Only one rank of DRAM can send data on a channel at a time, so a second access to the same channel must wait until the earlier access is completed before data can be sent (the command channel is separate, so there is some parallelism there). Each DRAM has several banks (e.g., 8) and in each bank only one row can be active at a time; it takes time to open a row and to close a row (and to access the data) during which no other action on that bank can be done. On an open row (DRAM page) hit, there is a small delay before

Comment: data transmission begins. On a page miss, if the bank has an active page, that page must be precharged/refreshed and the new row activated, otherwise the new row can begin activation immediately. Both precharge and row activation take time. Because DRAM uses a bidirectional data bus, there can also be write turnaround delay. In addition, there are queuing delays; because of the above and other complexities, scheduling of accesses can significantly increase effective bandwidth. There is also delay in reaching the memory controller, not just miss determination but on-chip network delay.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton could you move your comment to an answer so i can close it?